# How to let a function `clearInterval` itself?

Tags: javascript, ajax, setinterval, clearinterval

Somewhere in my code, i call this function:

```
function call_bid_button(id)
{
    bid_button(id);
    var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function(){bid_button(id)},1000);
}
```

Which as you can see calls the function `bid_button()` and sets an `interval` for it.

I want `bid_button()` to activate `clearInterval()` for itself. Here's `bid_button()`:

```
function bid_button(id)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200 && xmlhttp.responseText=='')
    {
        document.getElementById("bid_button").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
    }

    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","the_bid_button.php?id="+id,true);
    xmlhttp.send(); 
    return false;
}
```

As you can see, i'm trying to call `clearInterval()` from another function. Obviously, this won't work. What's the correct way to do it though?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually just pass a reference to the interval:

```
var interval_id;
interval_id = setInterval(function(){bid_button(id, interval_id); },1000);

function bid_button (id, interval_id) {
    clearInterval(interval_id);
}
```

This works because the callback function in the interval is called later.

Keep in mind though that because of the way `bid_button` is implemented some intervals may not get cleared. If you lose your internet connection for instance, it will keep trying and trying. The requests will resolve with `status=0`.

Comment: I thought about that, but i thought it wouldn't work. Now i see why it does work. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Set `refreshIntervalId` as a global variable, or at least within the scope of both functions.

```
var refreshIntervalId;

function call_bid_button(id)
{
    bid_button(id);
    refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function(){bid_button(id)},1000);
}

function bid_button(id)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200 && xmlhttp.responseText=='')
    {
        document.getElementById("bid_button").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
    }

    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","the_bid_button.php?id="+id,true);
    xmlhttp.send(); 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: If you call `bid_button` more than once per interval some of them will not be cleared. I would not recommend this solution. _"Use a global variable"_ should set off some alarm bells.

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer = setInterval(function(){
   alert('delayed 1ms');
},1000);
```

When this is through, as long as you arent calling it again, it is through. *If you are*,

```
clearInterval(timer);
```

IF the timer is wrapped in another function, the `var` makes it scoped to that function. You can either remove it to make it a global variable or execute it later in the same scope of the wrapped function.